# Backbone.js View Tagname set dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm trying to set up the base architecture for a Phonegap project using jQueryMobile and Backbone.js
We will be targeting multiple platforms and plan on expanding in the future.
I want my Backbone code to be completely ignorant of the types of HTML elements associated with the Views since we have no idea what the views will look like across the platforms.
A simple example would be that on one platform a List of items might be made from a `UL` and `LI` elements, but on another for some reason we might want to switch it to a `DIV` and `P` elements.

At the moment, if I don't specify a tagName, it defaults to a `DIV`.
I want to be able to provide a template like this on one page:

```
<script id="attachmentTemplate" type="text/template">
     <li><a href="#"><%= title %></a></li>
</script>
```

and on another provide:

```
<script id="attachmentTemplate" type="text/template">
    <p><a href="#"><%= title %></a></p>
</script>
```

I can't do that without specifying a tagName (as I said, it defaults to `DIV`).

Does anyone have any advice or methods to do this?  The key is that I don't want the Javascript to be aware of the type of HTML element, I want the HTML to define that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I wouldn't recommend this architecture you can override your render method:

```
render: function() 
{
    // unbind all handlers since delegateEvents was called in the constructor
    this.undelegateEvents();
    // set this.el to the domElement from the templates
    this.el = this.template(this.model.toJSON()); // or however you get to your template
    // create the shorthand dom reference that setElement() creates
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    // re-delegate the events
    this.delegateEvents();
}
```

what that means is that you don't need to worry about your tagName as you defined it in your template.

edit: looking through the Backbone code, this is exactly what `setElement` does, so in theory you could try

```
render: function() 
{
    var tpl = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    this.setElement(tpl, true);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I'm 100% brand new to Backbone, would you mind giving a bit more of an explanation as to what this code is doing?  I'm assuming that `delegateEvents` and `undelegateEvents` is your own practice and not a Standard?

Comment: By the way, my render function already includes this code: `$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));`  I don't understand the difference.

Comment: delegateEvents is a Backbone method that get called internally when a view's constructor method is called, what it does is bind the events specified in your view and attaches it. undelegateEvents undoes that. Check the documentation http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents and http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-undelegateEvents

Comment: I actually think I like your solution better than mine.  Seems cleaner.  However, will the setElement method fire off any unwanted events do you know?  Meaning, if I've assigned a "change" event or something, will it fire off during Render? (especially since this is really the first time I'm Rendering the element)

Comment: By the way, you might want to update your answer to include the fact that `this.template` must already be set.  I happened to have mine set during initialize like this: `this.template = _.template($('#attachmentTemplate').html());`

Comment: make a clear differentiation in your head between how backbone deals with DOM events (click, hover, ...) and binding events to your view/model/collection ... your change event is bound to a model or collection.

Comment: +1 I was using setElement in my view's initialize method, but after seeing your example, I moved it to the render method, which works much better!

Answer (score 13):

You can specify a tagName property in your view with a function, so it will be dynamic.

```
...

tagName: function(){
    return this.model.get('tagName');
},

...
```

Checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b7mR6/

Comment: This is the correct solution! @james-p-wright You should accept this!

Answer (score 1):

As usual, I search and search and find no answer, then I ask a question and figure it out on my own.

I discovered that if I make my Template like this:

```
<script id="attachmentTemplate" tagname="li" type="text/template">
    <a href="#"><%= title %></a>
</script>
```

Then in my js code, when instantiating my View I can do this:
`var attachmentView = new AttachmentListItemView({ tagName: $('#attachmentTemplate').attr('tagname'), model: item });`

And it works perfectly.
No idea if that will be valid HTML or cause any problems down the road though.

Comment: +1: seems elegant! I don't think extra arguments are a problem. XML is made that way to be extensible (and ignore extra attributes/elements the reader doesn't understand). So, IMHO, it's perfect.

Comment: This is a solution that works ok if you already have your templates preloaded on your page, might get tricky if you have to asynchronously load your templates, as the template won't have been inserted in the DOM.